# How to open a mp4 file and crop it, with with Lightworks

Tags: video, crop

Using UBUNTU 16 LTS and Lightworks (installed `lwks-14.0.0-amd64.deb`)... Need only to

- open a MP4 file for edition (how to?)
- edit by simple [crop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)) operation

but no clues at so complex and non-intuitive interface.

Answer (score 2):

At the top you'll see 4 tabs (**LOG | EDIT | VFX | AUDIO**). You'll have to select VFX and then click the **+** sight (top-left) to bring up the video efects grouped by category. Double click **Cine Crop 1** . Look left side (near bottom) there is a **Crop** sub-section (under **DVE** and under **Position** and **Scale** sub-sections ). Click arrow to expand, then you can pull the sliders to adjust your crop or double click percent box to edit manually.

[image: i think you'll understand quicker if you see]

Comment: But this leaves black space after the crop. How can I reduce video size **and** crop?

Answer (score 1):

Since the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576381/5120893) got a clarifying comment that was never answered, I suggest my workflow for cropping the video.

At the VFX tab in Lightworks, first change the **playback format** of the video. The sequence sub-window has a settings drop-down menu at the top right: press that and select a target playback format for your video.

[image: Playback format drop-down menu]

Then, add a **3D DVE** effect and set the *Position X*, *Y* and *Z* coordinates so that your video fits the playback format as you want.

[image: 3D DVE menu]